# How to share business logic among multiple applications using different apis with arcgis?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geoprocessing-service, arcgis-api-wpf

I've been working with ArcGIS and Esri WPF API for a year, but now me and my job colleagues felt the need to build a new application using the Esri Javascript API. Our application using WPF API has a lot of business logic that the new one certainly will have too. Is there a way to share this logic among the applications, considering that they use different APIs and must coexist?

Is building GP Services a good option for sharing this kind of logic (like validating feature insertions)?